# Setting an onClick listener to a layout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, layout, nullpointerexception

I have a `Relative layout` (useMe) that loads one of two fragments on creation depending on the orientation of the screen. I keep getting the error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference

the problem is this little bit of code right here

```
RelativeLayout useMe = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.startpage_activity);

useMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(StartPage.this, Question1.class);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

How is the `useMe` a null object?

Comment: `RelativeLayout` inside fragment or in Activity.

Comment: Have you used setContentView();

Answer (score 0):

Are you Trying to start another Activity?, or Another Fragment?

btw, you can use this set-up of Intent:

1st: include `android:OnClick= "useMe"` and `android:Clickable="true"` in your Relative layout and do this one:

```
public void useMe(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Question1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

hope it helps :D

P.S: if OnClick in RelativeLayout is not working, try it on LinearLayout, it is working 100% just include the Onclick and Clickable thingy in in your code :)

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Question1.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and define Activity in Manifest file

Comment: wonder how this Answer the Question why useMe object is NULL?

Comment: Please give me complete code so i can see your problem

Comment: This is an NPE problem. Not in launch activity process. Please be considerate. Before posting answer read considerately question.